# Filtering values after a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string `s` in python

```
ip access-list IpAclDscpTest
   10 permit ip any any dscp <value1>
   20 permit ip any any dscp <value2>
   30 permit ip any any dscp <value3>
   40 permit ip any any dscp <value4>
   50 permit ip any any dscp <value5
```

value<1-5> can be either numbers or string like `'abc31'`

example

```
txt = '''ip access-list IpAclDscpTest
   10 permit ip any any dscp 0
   20 permit ip any any dscp af31
   30 permit ip any any dscp ef
   40 permit ip any any dscp 34
   50 permit ip any any dscp 46'''
```

Is there any way to filter out the values after dscp and put them in a list using regex?

Comment: ouput = re.findall(r'dscp\s+(.*)\s+',s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do, it's a bit of a refinement on the other answers:

```
import re

txt = '''ip access-list IpAclDscpTest
   10 permit ip any any dscp 0
   20 permit ip any any dscp af31
   30 permit ip any any dscp ef
   40 permit ip any any dscp 34
   50 permit ip any any dscp 46'''

regex = r'''dscp\s+ # matches dscp and one or more spaces
            ([a-z0-9]+) # capture group, one or more lowercase alphanumerics
             \s*  # matches possible spaces after (0+)
              $ # this matches every endline (with MULTILINE flag below)
         '''

number_list = re.findall(regex, txt, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

and `number_list` returns you:

```
['0', 'af31', 'ef', '34', '46']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  for your new question.

```
ouput = re.findall(r'dscp\s+(.*)\s+',s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the front greedy

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input="""
ip access-list IpAclDscpTest
   10 permit ip any any dscp 0
   20 permit ip any any dscp 12
   30 permit ip any any dscp 18
   40 permit ip any any dscp 34
   50 permit ip any any dscp 46
"""

import re

for v in re.findall('.*dscp\s(\d+)', input):
    print v
```